# How can I inform the user with an alert from another Swift class and file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a Settingsviewcontroller.swift file that is connected to the storyboard and a separate file called connectionapi.swift.

Now, when a user clicks the checkbutton, the given username and password are checked against the API in the connectionapi class. Now when for instant the result generates an error I want to inform the user with an alert message. I am trying to find out for a few days how to do this, but I can't seem to find it. I keep ending up in errors.

Can someone please help me with some code examples:

**the viewcontroler file**

```
//
//  ViewControllerSettings.swift
//

import Foundation
import UIKit


class ViewControllerSettings: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tGebruikersnaam: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tCode: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AnimatedImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lCopyright: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lStatus: UILabel!


    // declare a iCloud Store to save and load data from
    var iCloudStore:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore!
    var userName:String = ""
    var password:String = ""

    let API = myAPI()


    @IBAction func didTapOpslaan(_ sender: Any) {
        if tGebruikersnaam.text == "" || tGebruikersnaam.text == nil || tCode.text == "" || tCode.text == nil {
            return
        }

        print("Lets check username and password against the api")

        let newUsername = "\(tGebruikersnaam.text!)"
        let newCode = "\(tCode.text!)"




        API.CheckUsernamePassword(username: newUsername, code: newCode)  {
            isValid in
            print(isValid)

            if isValid == true {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("The credentials are correct")
                    self.ShowAnimationOk()
                }
            }else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("the credentials are wrong")
                    self.ShowAnimationNo()
                }
            }


        }

    }

//  Code removed     

}
```

**The API Swift file**

```
//
//  ConnectAPI.swift


import Foundation
import UIKit




class myAPI{

    let api_key = "b88a734f186sad"
    let baseurl = "https://xxxx:443/xxxx/api"

    func CheckUsernamePassword(username :String ,code:String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->() )  {


        let urlString = "\(self.baseurl)/accounts/validateusernamepassword.json?username=\(username)&password=\(code)&api_key=\(self.api_key)"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("API | Error URLSession : \(error!)")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                do {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]

                    print("----------")


                    if parsedData["validated"] != nil {
                        if "\(parsedData["validated"]!)" == "1" {
                            print("API JSON | validated = \(parsedData["validated"]!)")
                            print("API JSON | message   = \(parsedData["message"]!)")
                            completion(true)

                        }else {
                            print("Credential Check not valid")
                            print("API JSON | validated = \(parsedData["validated"]!)")
                            print("API JSON | message   = \(parsedData["message"]!)")
                            completion(false)

                        }


                    }else{
                        print("Json Parse error: \(parsedData)")

                        // Raise a Alert here
                    }


                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("API | Error Parsing JSON \(error)" )


                      // Raise a Alert here
                      // main.showAlert(message: "API | Error Parsing JSON \(error)")

                      //A error occured when checking credentials, try again later.

                    completion(false)
                }
            }

            }.resume()

    }
```

Comment: what error do you get? What's not working in your current code? Is your completion block running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your problem is. I assume that you have two problems:

1. you don't know how to pass error message from your API class to
   the ViewControllerSettings class.
2. you don't know how to show alert in iOS before

If that's the case, let's look at this.

---

**1. Passing error message**

You can see that the completion block (e.g., @escaping (Bool) -> ()) will be called after the function checkUsernamePassword done with the URLSession's dataTask:

```
func CheckUsernamePassword(username :String ,code:String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->() )  { ... }
```

If success, you call the block with value true

```
completion(true)
```

in other cases you call with value false

```
completion(false)
```

To pass more informations (e.g. error message), you can simply add input parameter at the completion block. Better added names for each one so it's more clear. E.g., change it to:

```
..., completion: @escaping (valid: Bool, errorMessage: String?) -> ())
```

Then, if the API succeeds, you call it without errorMessage:

```
completion(valid: true, errorMessage: nil)
```

And if it's error, you pass either your own error message or get it from NSError

```
completion(valid: false, errorMessage: "Credential check not valid.")
```

---

**2. Show the error in UIAlertController**

First make a utility function that shows standard alert in your ViewControllerSettings:

```
// Simple Alert UI
func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
     let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

     // add close button
     let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel) { _ in }
     actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

     // show on self
     self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If you did the first step, you have accessed to your error message at call site (ViewController).

When you call the API, errorMessage is available, just show it with alert:

```
// didTap...
API.CheckUsernamePassword(username: newUsername, code: newCode)  {
   (isValid, errorMessage) in
    if isValid {
        ...
    } else {
        let error = errorMessage! // I don't recommend forced-casting though
        self.showAlert(title: "Error!", message: error) // show Alert UI
    }
}
```